# How to detect a non-consumable in-app item has been refunded in SKPaymentTransactionObserver?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I am testing using local StoreKit, for non consumable in-app item.

If I purchase the non consumable in-app item, I can receive callback in `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` without issue

```
extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                complete(transaction)
            ...
        }
    }

    private func complete(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("complete...")

        // Save purchase record to disk to indicate user owns this non-consumable item.
        persistPurchase(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
```

If I go to Debug/ StoreKit/ Manage Transactions... , to perform refund, I do not receive any callback in `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`.

Even if I close the app and start the app again, there isn't any callback to `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`, to indicate the non consumable in-app item has been refunded, so that I can block user from accessing the in-app item.

May I know, is it possible to detect a non-consumable in-app item has been refunded, in `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`? If not, what is the right way to do so?

Comment: Refund transactions are not delivered to your transaction observer. They are delivered to the server url (if any) that you configure in App Store Connect.

Comment: I just notice to do so, I need to invest my own server, and the receipt should be sent to my server for "decoding", every-time during app startup. If I want to avoid such workload & additional investment, I guess I should upgrade to iOS15 (from iOS14) and start to use StoreKit 2 `Transaction.currentEntitlements`, right?